# CLion or CMake: Delete copied file in binary directory if source file in the source directory is deleted

Tags: build, cmake, clion

I also want the files in the build directory to be deleted if they're deleted in the source directory. Does anyone know a way to do this? I was only able to find similar solutions that didn't have the deletion.

Comment: What files are in the build directory, which are also in the source directory? Why do they get copied?

Comment: What's the rationale of this? Just ignore the files or delete the build directory.

Comment: Navigating to and deleting the build directory is a pain, and whether the files are there or not makes a difference to the program.

Comment: If it is just navigation: You can create symbolic links from your build directory to your source directory. This can simplify life a lot.

Answer (score 1):

From a CMake point of view: You have to delete your build directory and rerun CMake.

Comment: Darn. That's a pain.